# dpi of the image in the drawable folders

Tags: android, image, drawable, resolution, dpi

I'm currently designing images in four different dimensions (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi) for an Android application. i know that the different drawable folders are used dependig on the dpi of the devices' screen.

But what is the optimal dpi in photoshop to save the pngs?

Should images for ldpi saved with 120dpi, mdpi with 160dpi and so on?

Comment: But I too want exact answer for you questions.

Comment: check out my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9636141/1012284

Comment: well, the launcher ic_launcher_template.psd provided by Android is a 72dpi photoshop file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// check this [Link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/)

You might be confused about what PPI (pixels per inch) to set your deliverables at. Just leave them at the standard **72 PPI**, and scale the images accordingly.

Comment: I would avoid using a standard size for images in the ldpi folder as suggested in number 2 from this link about optimizing projects: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/

Comment: Throwing any dpi image into the ldpi folder will slow down an android app when deployed onto screens with different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this,

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

According to that,

[image]

What I would do is design on a 300dpi cavas. That way there's no loss of quality.

Answer (score 0):

Picture's resolution is not important for screen, it's important only for printing.